# How Do I pass data to Springboot post endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot

I got stock here and I need help.
I am writing an endpoint to get data from the request body.
My Spring application is returning error.

```java
/* CreteStudentRequest Model */
public class CreateStudentRequest {
    String first_name;
    String last_name; 
    String email;
}
```

```java
/* Post endpoint */
@PostMapping("/create")
@ResponseBody
public CreateStudentRequest addStudent(@RequestBody CreateStudentRequest csr ) {

   System.out.println("This is Cool... add Student post endpoint"); 

   //return studentservice.createStudent("LOT","2ray","2ray@gmail.com");

   return csr;   
}
```

```java
/* Error I get */
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.validation.annotation.ValidationAnnotationUtils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.validateIfApplicable(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:243) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:137) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
```

Comment: Fix code formatting please

Comment: You used a Validation annotation somewhere, which you didn't show us, but you didn't include the Spring Validation library. Add missing dependency.